# Cannot connect to Database server (mysql workbench)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Could you help me solve this problem ?

When I try to click "query database" under database menu in Mysql workbench. it gives me an error:

> Cannot Connect to Database Server
>
> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at
> 127.0.0.1:3306:Can't connect to mysql server on '127.0.0.1'(10061)
>
> Please:
>
> 1. Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
> 2. Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
> 3. Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)
> 4. Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're connecting from

Comment: related http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44485/i-cant-get-mysql56-service-to-start-after-i-stopped-it

Comment: This answer worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129399/mysql-workbench-cannot-connect-to-database-server

Comment: In my case simple restart help - but I firstly check @sergio suggestion - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875732/6705161.

Comment: On windows, make sure you log on as a local system rather than as a network service. FULL INSTRUCTIONS HERE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73968917/6495588

Answer (score 144):

The issue is likely due to socket authentication being enabled for the root user by default when no password is set, during the upgrade to ubuntu 16.04.

The solution is to revert back to native password authentication. You can do this by logging in to MySQL using socket authentication by doing:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

Once logged in:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

which will revert back to the native (old default) password authentication.

Now use **password** as the password whenever required by MySQL.

Comment: It worked for me, I'm surprised, I've already configured the strict password while installing the mysql and same strict password used with given alter query. I'm curios to know why it didnt worked in first attempt itself

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is this behavior only created for the benefit of the unix root user doing the login to mysql without enter the password?

Comment: How to do this on Windows? After I set a password I am getting the same problem. Weird that MySQL get's an error after setting the password, it is like they don't want anyone to use their DB framework.

Comment: If you are using `snap` to install mysql workbench, try this: `sudo snap connect mysql-workbench-community:password-manager-service :password-manager-service
` to allow sandboxed package to access password service. https://askubuntu.com/a/1242777/1621549

Comment: I tried using this command on MariaDB 10.1.48 and got the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" :/

Comment: I did the `sudo mysql_secure_installation` and selected the zero-level password strenght option (low). It made me run into this error, and this answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 66):

Try opening `services.msc` from the start menu search box and try manually starting the MySQL service or directly write `services.msc`  in `Run` box

Comment: Did not work for me. running directly from the command line ´C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe --console´ (notice the "d" between "mysql" and ".exe" did work though (when opening the command line "as administrator"). So I supose finding a way to start the service "as administrator" would solve this.

Comment: Where is the start menu search box?

Comment: My solution was run Mysql-Workbench with sudo: `sudo mysql-workbench`
 . Didn't know where to find services.msc

Answer (score 40):

It looks like there are a lot of causes of this error.

## My Cause / Solution

In my case, the cause was that my server was configured to only accept connections from localhost. I fixed it by following this article: [How Do I Enable Remote Access To MySQL Database Server?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html). My `my.cnf` file had no `skip-networking` line, so I just changed the line

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

This allows connections from any IP, not just 127.0.0.1.

Then, I created a MySql user that could connect from my client machine by running the following terminal commands:

```
# mysql -u root -p
mysql> CREATE USER 'username'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    -> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'1.2.3.4' WITH GRANT OPTION;
    -> \q
```

where `1.2.3.4` is the IP of the client you are trying to connect from. If you really have trouble, you can use `'%'` instead of `'1.2.3.4'` to allow the user to connect from any IP.

## Other Causes

For a fairly extensive list, see [Causes of Access-Denied Errors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-connecting.html).

Comment: AFAIK, the creation of the user is necessary because the user root should only be used for admin work and sensibly that should be limited to localhost. what user you create beyond that is up to you!

Comment: Link to Causes of Access-Denied Errors is now broken.

Comment: i was facing similar issue ,what worked for me is 
mysql> CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password123#@!';
    -> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
    -> \q
i didn't had to do  binding thing,
my password was set to Medium, you can check using "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';"
 Note: this is my dev ubuntu setup

Answer (score 22):

Did you try to determine if this is a problem with Workbench or a general connection problem? Try this:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306`
3. If you can connect successfully you will see a mysql prompt after you type your password (type `quit` and Enter there to exit).

Report back how this worked.

Comment: Hi, It says "mysql is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Thank you so much.

Comment: You might want to add [the mysql bin directory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-installation-layout.html) (the `bin` directory within the main MySQL directory) to [the system path](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx). Then the mysql client program will be available from anywhere. Or you can just run that command after cd-ing to the MySQL bin directory. Both should work.

Comment: When i connecting to mysql with this command $> mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
[root@localhost ~]# mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[root@localhost ~]# mysql -u admin -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[root@localhost ~]#

Comment: Worked for me!! Thx a lot!

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar issue on **Mac OS** and I was able to fix it this way:

From the terminal, run:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
```

Then, I was asked to enter the password. I just pressed **enter** since no password was setup.

I got a message as follows:

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. Your MySQL
>   connection id is 181. Server version: 8.0.11 Homebrew.

If you succeeded to log into mysql>, run the following command:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

You should get a message like this:

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

Now, your password is "**password**" and your username is "**root**".

Happy coding :)

Comment: This will probably no longer work with newer installations as anonymous log ins are disabled.

Answer (score 13):

Run the ALTER USER command. Be sure to change password to a strong password of your choosing.

1. `sudo mysql` # Login to mysql`
2. Run the below command

   ```
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
   ```

Now you can access it by using the new password.

Ref : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 7):

The error occur because the mysql server is not starting on your computer. You should start it manually. Do following steps:

1. Download and install wamp server according to your bit version(32bit or 64bit) in your       computer(http://wampserver-64bit.en.softonic.com/) this link allows you to download wamp server for 64bit.
2. As soon as you install it you can double click and run it..(you can see a icon in the right hand of the taskbar.It may be hidden .so you can click the arrow which show you the hide apps runing).So click the icon and go to ***Mysql***
3. Then go to ***Service*** and there you can find ***Start/Resume Services*** click on it..
4. And now it is done.Open mysql workbench and see.It will work..

Answer (score 6):

I had to start Workbench as Administrator. Apparently it didn't have the required permissions to connect to my localhost database server process.

Right-click the Workbench shortcut and select `Run as Administrator`. In the shortcut's Properties window, you can click on "Advanced" and tick the box next to "Run as Administrator" to always run the Workbench with Admin privileges.

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem with Workbench on Ubuntu, problem was with permission.

1. Find Workbench app
2. Click button Permissions
3. Give all permission for this app

[image]

Comment: Perfect!. If the server runs and all you get is the error msg, then this might be the issue

Answer (score 5):

Even I faced a similar error when I opened [MySQL Workbench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench).
The solution that worked for me was:

1. Click on the **Start** button on a [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) machine
2. Type **services** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Find **MySQL** and click on it
4. On the top side of the left panel, you will find an option as **Start the service**
5. Click on **Start** which is visible as a hyperlink

Comment: (Sorry. Edit blunder for revision 3 (pasting into the wrong answer...). Less likely is a system glitch.)

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this problem for awhile and did several reinstalls of MySQL before discovering this.

I know that MySQL server was running OK because I could access all my DB's using the command line.

Hope this works for you.

In **MySQL Workbench (5.2.47 CE)**

click **Mange Server Instances** (bottom right corner)

click **Connection**

in the **Connection** box select:

**Local Instance ($ServerName) - root@127.0.0.1:3306 '<'Standard(TCP/IP)>**

click **Edit Selected...**

under **Parameters, Hostname** change **localhost or 127.0.0.1** to your NetBIOS name

click **Test Connection**

If this works for you, great. If not change the hostname back to what it was.

Comment: THIS worked for me. NetBIOS name is the computer's name, you can read it from the system properties, 'Computer name' tab, 'full computer name'.

Answer (score 3):

Forr me reason was that I tried to use newest MySQL Workbench 8.x to connect to MySQL Server 5.1 (both running on Windows Server 2012).

When I uninstalled MySQL Workbench 8.x and installed MySQL Workbench 6.3.10 it successfully connected to `localhost` database

Answer (score 3):

For those who ignored that the initial error message displaying is the following one:

*The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files*

Make sure to install gnome-keyring using the following

```
sudo apt install gnome-keyring
```

Answer (score 3):

#### The problem is that MySQL server is not installed.

You can get the installer from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/).

Then watch this [6-minute installation tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u96rVINbAUI).

---

If then creating a new connection in [MySQL Workbench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench) is not working, make sure you run that connection as root as show below:

[image]

If you don't find your *.ini* file, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28684866/11322237) (also written below).

> - Enter "services.msc" on the Start menu search box.
> - Find MySQL service under Name column, for example, MySQL56.
> - Right click on MySQL service, and select Properties menu.
> - Look for "Path To Executable" under General tab, and there is your .ini file, for instance, "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MYSQL56

Answer (score 3):

I tried these steps -

**Step 1 :** Go to **Ubuntu Software Center**

**Step 2 :** Searched for **MySql Workbench**

**Step 3 :** And Click on **Permissions**

**Step 4 :** Enable **Read, add, change or remove saved passwords**

Then, enter **Login Password**

And then, I found that my **problem solved**[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was in similar situations before and last time I found it was some Windows update issue(not sure). This time, I opened MySQL workbench and found no connection to my local database. I cannot see my tables, but yesterday I could connect to the database.

I found that my cause is that, after letting my computer sleeping for some time and wake it again, the mysql service is not running. 
My solution: restart the service named "mysql" and rerun the workbench. Restarting the service takes a while, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

To be up to date for upper versions and later visitors :

Currently I'm working on a win7 64bit having different tools on it including python 2.7.4 as a prerequisite for google android ...

When I upgraded from WB 6.0.8-win32 to upper versions to have 64bit performance I had some problems for example on 6.3.5-winx64 I had a bug in the details view of tables (disordered view) caused me to downgrade to 6.2.5-winx64.

As a GUI user, easy forward/backward engineering and db server relative items were working well but when we try to `Database>Connect to Database` we will have `Not connected` and will have python error if we try to execute a query however the DB server service is absolutely ran and is working well and this problem is not from the server and is from workbench. To resolve it we must use `Query>Reconnect to Server` to choose the DB connection explicitly and then almost everything looks good (this may be due to my multiple db connections and I couldn't find some solution to define the default db connection in workbench).

As a note : because I'm using latest Xampp version (even in linux addictively :) ), recently Xampp uses mariadb 10 instead of mysql 5.x causes the mysql file version to be 10 may cause some problems such as forward engineering of procedures which can be resolved via `mysql_upgrade.exe` but still when we try to check a db connection wb will inform about the wrong version however it is not critical and works well.

Conclusion : Thus sometimes db connection problems in workbench may be due to itself and not server (if you don't have other db connection relative problems).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have just installed MySQL Workbench but after uninstalling MySQL Workbench and installing MySQL installer and is same for both 32 and 64 bit then after it working like a charm. Hope it could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I just use:

```
sudo snap connect mysql-workbench-community:ssh-keys

sudo snap connect mysql-workbench-community:password-manager-service
```

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this problem for quite a while.

I came accross this [interesting thread from MySQL forum: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,11388,11388#msg-11388](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,11388,11388#msg-11388)

I also came accross (obviously) some good SO Q/A.

It seems that the message mentioned in "user948950" 's question can be coming from a wide range of reasons: log file too big, incorrect mysql.ini file values, spaces in the file path, security/acl issue, old entries in the registry, and so on.

So, after trying for 3h to fix this... I abandonned and decided to do a good old re-install.

This is where [this post from (again) this MySQL thread came in useful](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,11388,15452#msg-15452), I quote:

> Gary Williams wrote:  Hi Guys,
>
> I've had exactly the same problem and this is how  I got it working
>   for me, starting with a non  working installation.
>
> 1. Stop the windows service for any existing mysql  installation.
> 2. Uninstall Mysql.
>
> As with most uninstalls, old files are left  behind. If your directory
>   is C:\mysql\ etc then  delete the innob, etc, files but leave the 
>   directories themselves as well as any existing  databases in 'data'.
>   If your directory is  C:\Program Files\ etc, delete all the mysql 
>   directories.
>
> 1. It's now worth running regedit to make sure  the old registry entries are deleted as well by  the uninstall. If not, delete them.
> 2. It's ok to use the new .msi installer  (essential files only), however ....
> 3. Do not use their default install path! Some  genius set a path with spaces in it! Choose the  custom install and select a sensible path,
>      ie,  C:\mysql  (note from Adrien: C:\mysqldata for ... the data)
> 4. Do not choose to alter the security settings.  Uncheck the relevant box and the install will  complete without having to set a root
>      password.
>
> I think I have remembered everything.
>
> Good luck
>
> Gary

I did get into troubles when simply copy/pasting the databases I had in my previous "data" directory to the new one. So the work around I found was to export each database (I know... a lot of fun) and then re-import them one by one.

FYI: I used the following command to import `C:/<MySQLInstallDir>/My SQL Server x.x/bin/mysql -u root -p <dbName> < "<dirPathOfDump>\<dumpName>.sql"`, that is for instance `C:/mysql/MySQL Server 5.6/bin/mysql -u root -p mySupaCoolDb < "C:\mySupaCoolDbDump20130901.sql"`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the MySQL server wasn't actually installed. I had run the MySQL Installer, but it didn't install the MySQL server.

I reran the installer, click "Add", and then added MySQL server to the list. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

2022 and beyond this works for me:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

change

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Then remember to restart mysql `sudo systemctl restart mysql`

Comment: This presumes some kind of Linux system. Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72974902/edit) information about it to your answer (distribution, version, [systemdness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), etc.)? But ********* ***without*** ********* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was confused, but I was able to solve the problem.

If your workbench was downloaded through the [Snap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(software)) package manager you could easily use this command to solve the problem, very simple:

```
sudo snap connect mysql-workbench-community:password-manager-service :password-manager-service
```

Comment: This presumes some kind of Linux system. Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73481045/edit) information about it to your answer (distribution, version, etc.)? But ********* ***without*** ********* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *services.msc* and find MySQL.

If "**Log on As**" section is 'Network Service', then:

1. Double click on the MySQL row to open a pop-up
2. go to "Log on" tab
3. Select Log on as: "**Local System account**" and check "*Allow service to interact with desktop*"

Voilà, now you can start your service on localhost and make sure you enter correct root/user password on your [MySQL Workbench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench), and you are good to go.

Comment: This seems to presume some kind of Windows system. Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73968917/edit) information about it to your answer (edition, Windows Server/desktop, version, etc.)? But ********* ***without*** ********* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using snap to install mysql workbench, try this:

```
sudo snap connect mysql-workbench-community:password-manager-service :password-manager-service  to allow sandboxed package to access password service
```

[askubuntu.com/a/1242777/1621549](https://askubuntu.com/a/1242777/1621549)

This Solution was made as a comment before by Rohim Chou

Answer (score 0):

go to services find mySql (from start)

start the service
once the server starts you can start working in sql workbench

2. if you don't find my sql in services than follow the below steps
   open cmd(run as administrator otherwise it won't work)
   go to the following path (write this command)

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin(check the path from your local)

> dir mysqld.exe /s /p(this will find the path of mysqld)
> (if you dont have mysqld install it)
> mysqld.exe --install
> mysqld.exe --initialize

this will do the work
now go to sdervices and start the server

Answer (score 0):

I Faced this issue for MAC recently and here is the solution:

1. Search *MySql* globally on your MAC in System Settings and open it.
2. Choose the Active instance and Stop MySql Server.
3. Initialize Database and configure a new password and save it.
4. Now relaunch your Workbench and test the connection with the new password
   and it will work.