# MySQL Workbench Cannot Connect to Database Server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have exactly the same problem as the poster in question [7864276](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864276/cannot-connect-to-database-server-mysql-workbench) except that in my case I've verified that the server is actually running, e.g., from within MySQL Workbench by right-clicking on Local Instance MySQL and selecting Start Command Line Client.  It's only when I select Query Database or double click on Local Instance MySQL that the error message results.  One additional piece of information in the error message is that it says "invalid for this platform requested(MYSQL_PROTOCOL_SOCKET)".  Everything worked fine until I recently updated MySQL Workbench to version 5.2.47 CE.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in 5.2.47 with explicit socket names. I'll be testing with 6.0 shortly.

Comment: I was connecting with root and it wouldn't work. Add a user on command line and then use that. Without taking the time to figure it out, I think it might have something to do with the mysql security settings set when installing mysql. (no root access from network??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on Manage Connections.  Select Local Instance MySQL.  Change Connection Method to Local Socket/Pipe.  Test connection succeeds now.

Answer (score -2):

TERMINAL:

```
sudo mysql -u root ENTER
you password user ENTER
USE mysql; ENTER
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root'; ENTER
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; ENTER
exit; ENTER
service mysql restart ENTER
you password user again ENTER
```

finish you terminal, and enter Mysql Workbench, in Mysql Connections "key icon", local instance 3306, and Test connection.