# Cannot connect to Azure MySQL service with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, azure, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench on a 64bit/Win 8.1 machine to trying to connect to an Azure MySQL service, but everytime I get the following error:

> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error:0

I followed many tutorial found ever the internet, and I also tried to disable temporarely the firewall: most of them says that the only needed parameters are:

- hostname (the one given in Azure portal/MyDB/Properties)
- username (the one given in Azure portal/MyDB/Properties)
- (optional) password (to store in vault)

I tried also using different connection methods (Standard TCP/IP and Local socket/pipe, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129399/mysql-workbench-cannot-connect-to-database-server)) but nothing.

Can help?

Comment: What do you mean by, "Azure MySQL service?" Is this a MySQL database in ClearDB or is this a MySQL database in an Azure Virtual Machine?

Comment: It's a MySQL database in ClearDB.

Comment: Now it seems that my company network is blocking the access. It is strange, because from telnet I get: "5.5.42-logkù«u\KLMfs!☻└§>fi[m4CG2k,Fmysql_native_password"

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to recreate your issue. Here are the steps that I tried with a MySQL database created thru the Azure portal.

1. Open MySql Workbench.
2. Setup new connection with the following settings.
3. Hostname: HOSTNAME
4. Port: PORT
5. Username: USERNAME
6. Pasword: PASSWORD
7. Database: DATABASE NAME
8. Test Connection > Succeeded.

The settings above came from portal.azure.com > MyDatabase > All settings.

One suggestion is to contact ClearDB support. You can login to ClearDB from your database's Azure dashboard by clicking on Manage Database. From there you can go to Support and log a support incident.

Comment: Thanks, it should definitely be a network limitation from my company network.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with a similar issue, as I was not able to connect my MySQL workbench with Azure VM that's running MySQL.

I've contacted the Azure support to help me out after trying it for 3-4 hrs.

They suggested me to go into network security group of that VM, and add 3306 or whatever port that your MySQL is running on our Azure to the inbound and outbound list and add the exception as All.

It helped me to connect MySQL workbench with Azure VM with MySQL on it.