# Can't connect to Mysql by Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench

[image]

I can confirm my username and password are correct. 
I can connect to RDS by **php** with no problem.  I can also use **Terminal/shell** to connect to RDS.
I used to connect to RDS by Mysql Workbench successfully for many times.

> What's difference between pem on the shell and pem on the GUI. I use Mac OS, So my shell is Terminal.

I check my grants.
I do think it's enough for me to connect to Mysql.

Mysql Workbench gives me error:

> Authentication error. Please check that your username and password are
>   correct and try again. Details (Original exception message):
>   Authentication failed.

And Navicat for MySQL gives me error:

> SSH tunnel: Bad private key!

But pem works good in bash.
I'm really confused.....
What's wrong? I have no clue.

Comment: Can you provide us with a bit more information?

Comment: MySQL Workbench is not a DBMS, it's just an app to simplify its use.

Comment: @Alex It's from Mysql Workbench: Authentication error. Please check that your username and password are correct and try again.
Details (Original exception message):
Authentication failed.

Comment: @arielnmz Sorry, I wrote my title by mistake and updated just now. Plz check! I used to use MySQL Workbench as a DBMS with the same username and password.

Comment: @anna I wouldn't know what's causing your issue, May sound like a stupid suggestion, but Maybe double check all of the details you have entered? For example, you may have entered the host name wrong? Other than that, I don't think I can really offer any help sorry

Edit: Maybe check out this? May be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864276/cannot-connect-to-database-server-mysql-workbench

Comment: Also check the input method you used to connect, sometimes the encoding is an issue. Check the keyboard distribution too (a Shift+3 (·) ≠ Shift+3 (#) on Spanish vs Latin American distributions, for example).

Comment: @arielnmz I have double checked that I use the English keyboard. I tried another MySQL tool called Navicat for MySQL, and it gave me error : SSH tunnel: Bad private key! Do you know this error? What's difference between pem on the shell and pem on the GUI. I use Mac OS, So my shell is Terminal.

Comment: @Alex ...I wouldn't know, either. Really killing me.

Comment: @anna Yeah I bet it's a real pain, can't you just connect to mysql without mysql workbench? I Guess that's your alternative

Comment: @Alex Yeah I have to be a good shell writer:) Interesting when I begin to give up GUI.

Comment: Have you achieved a correct login? which password did you use? It all points out to a bad password… maybe you wrote it wrong twice at setup?

Comment: @arielnmz You know what! I just tried a new connection, and MySQL Workbench gave an error: 'Authentication failed, please check credentials.Please refer to logs for details.' It seemed like my pem had problem. I already chmod 400 for pem.