# MySQL Error: Access denied for user root@localhost

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySQL. I have installed MySQL 5.6 in Windows 7 with user root and given password to it. But when I start MySQL Workbench and try to connect database, I am getting an error.

**My try**:

**Connect to Database**:

[image]

**Connect to MySQL Server**:

[image]

**Error**:

[image]

**Then I tried to reset password with command prompt**:

[image]

Please help me, I am new to MySQL, not getting what to do.
Thanks

Comment: I think this is the similar problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864276/cannot-connect-to-database-server-mysql-workbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your setup is not listening for IP connections and is only listening on a local socket. Try:

```
mysql -u root
```

If you have already set a root password, try:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

on the command prompt. Or try removing the hostname from workbench.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this issue using these steps.

1.open the terminal

2.exectute the command - `sudo mysql -u root`

3.then,execute - `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new_password';`(*replace the "new_password" with your new password"

4.`exit;`

5.now check the connection...It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have access for such task, exit the application and re-start it as administrator . `Run As Administrator`

Comment: Nope! That's not an issue. Still getting same error.