# Cannot Connect to Database Server MySQL Workbench Tunnel Error

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, networking

Every time I try to connect to my mySQL on mysql workbench, it gives me this error message saying:

Your connection attempted failed for user 'root' from your host to server at http:x.x.x.x:3306: Cannot open SSH Tunnel:Error connecting SSH tunnel:Error Connecting to SSH server Error 11004 get addrinfo failed

Comment: To increase the chance of somebody answering your question, please read the article ["How to ask?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to add some more detail to your question.

Comment: you are able to connect using terminal ?
mysql -u username -p -h hostname

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect using terminal.

Comment: I am certain this is a duplicate. Search with google and you will find.

Comment: I already tried searching with google

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to Database server (mysql workbench)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864276/cannot-connect-to-database-server-mysql-workbench)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get solution here: http://quintagroup.com/services/support/tutorials/mysql-linux

or follow this steps:
Open putty and accept the certificate of the server
hostname should be localhost ( in order to use local socket and not http conection)

local port should be something like 33010 not 3306
local port is the conection back port used by the plink and has nothing to do with mysql ports

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     

When I ran netstat, this is the port it is listening on. I am not sure if everything else is correct. 

I set my Msql hostname in my mysql workbench settings as :127.0.0.1

Is this correct?

Comment: You can set it as localhost or 127.0.0.1