# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) on MAC OSX

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm trying to reinstall mysql on my MAC OS X Yosemite. for this I followed the instruction as mentioned below

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
vim /etc/hostconfig and removed the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

I also tried

```
brew uninstall mysql
```

after this I installed mysql using homebrew using command `brew install mysql`.
After installation when I tried to run `mysql -u root` It throws the following error

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

I didn't set password for mysql.I don't know what's going wrong.Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try password reset: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Did you tried `mysql -u root -p`?

Comment: yes I tried it.but it ask for password and on pressing entering it raise above error

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326065/unable-to-access-mysql-after-it-automatically-generated-a-temporary-password/33332443#33332443

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I installed `mysql` with `homebrew` and got the same problem as you because `mysql` has had an existing database with an existing password there. See [this article](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/10503#issuecomment-283587609) for more details.

```
$ brew services stop mysql
$ sudo pkill mysqld
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql/ # NOTE: this will delete your existing database!!!
$ brew postinstall mysql
$ brew services restart mysql
$ mysql -uroot
```

Comment: Does anyone have any update on this? I tried this and still having the same error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@localhost`

Comment: found this the best solution. Had to run `sudo pkill mysqld`

Comment: Perfect solution! After a lot of struggle, ended up here and saved! Thanks.
After that if you want to reset the password, execute

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`

credits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864276/cannot-connect-to-database-server-mysql-workbench

Comment: I come from the future where a mysterious pandemic has taken over the world , And THIS is the only solution that works as of NOV-01-2020. Thanks!

Comment: this gives a new error. 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Answer (score 9):

Now sql generates an aliatory password that appears in the last screen.

```
sudo mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p
Enter password: (aliatory password)
```

we can change it

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new-password';
```

Comment: how can you change it if you can't log into mysql?

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved this issue for myself.

Please check my github with this link: https://github.com/LeVanTuan/access_sql

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES/NO)
>
> Fix bug access denied on macos 10.12 (Sierra)
>
> install mysql (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) if already
>   installed, skip this step
>
> Update password of 'root' to access.
>
> Open Terminal (Launchpad -> Other -> Terminal or (Command + space) ->
>   Type 'terminal' )
>
> Then type follow below:
>
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
>
> sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
>
> then, restart Terminal (quit then open again)
>
> then, keep type:
>
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
>
> mysql -u root mysql
>
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
>
> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
>
> \q
>
> sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
>
> extra: start mysql: sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
>   --skip-grant-tables stop mysql: sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 3):

In my case with a **Mac M1** and **Mysql 8.0.29-arm64** this answer worked for me:

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/sql/how+to+reset+root+password+in+mysql+m1+mac;

Run the server in safe mode with privilege bypass:

```
> sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

In a new Terminal window

```
> mysql -u root
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

Then

```
> mysql -u root
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd';
```

Comment: When go to the new Terminal window, using the `mysql -u root`; it raises an error. The same password error

Comment: Thank you, the --skip-grant-tables fixed it for me. I'm using `mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables` in this case

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling mysql completely and installing with an installer solved the problem for me.

Solution:

- [Remove mysql complete from your computer](https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d)
- [Download and Install mysql without brew](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). Specify your desire password here or based on the version the installer might mention you a password
- set the path for for mysql

  `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`
- Check whether its installed properly `mysql --version`
- `mysql -uroot p` to login
- change the password if required `mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root')`

Answer (score 1):

I spent 5 hours on this error today, tried every solution that exists out there, and even re-installed MySQL several times but what worked for me:

while installing in the configuration settings instead of `"Use Strong Password Encryption"` I selected `"Use Legacy Password Encryption"` and everything worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the commands mentioned in the stackoverflow, but nothing worked. Finally, I deleted every mysql folder in mac and reinstalled mysql. Finally the command

```
mysql -u root
```

worked for me. Then atlast, I set password for the mysql root by editing the configuration file.

Comment: I have tried to install mariadb on a Mac M1 but on trying to access with "mariadb -u root -p" always get the error:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

No solution presented here works and there is no explanation why this happens in the mac yet easily installs on other OSes

I would really love to get Mariadb or Mysql running on my Mac and not have to look for Windows to test my apps ;(

Answer (score 0):

****on your mac terminal type**
mysql -u root -p

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reset your temporary password. Re-install mysql, use the temporary password to connect to mysql and run:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_new_password');
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for anyone still not finding a resolution with a new M1 Mac. This completely clears your database FYI!!

First run brew services stop mysql

I found it easier to just open finder and use the got to folder and open /opt/homebrew, under the var folder I deleted the MySQL folder and under locks I deleted the MySQL lock files.

brew install MySQL and followed the install again.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above methods work, try the following method, which is applicable for macOS 13, MySQL 8, and installation via Homebrew.

1: unistall mysql: brew uninstall mysql

2 run cmd : ps -ax | grep mysql | grep -v grep

It will return a result:

3964 ??         0:00.03 /bin/sh /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql

4065 ??         0:02.26 /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql --

Remember the path /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/

3 : Kill all PIDs that you receive , Example: sudo kill 3964

4 : Delete the mysql directory in the path obtained above /opt/homebrew/opt/.

5 : Finally, reinstall MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and then type your password which you created during installation to enter to mysql.