# Unable to access MySQL after it automatically generated a temporary password

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-elcapitan, sequelpro

I have erased and installed `OSX 10.11 El Capitan` and I have been following through [this tutorial](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/) to get `MySQL` up and running on the new OS X. The first step was to download [MySQL For Mac OS X 10.9 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) (works on 10.11, they recommended in the tutorial). While I were finishing installing the MySQL, I got the message saying that :

```
2015-10-25T02:10:54.549219Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: R>gFySuiu23U

If you lose this password, please consult the section How to Reset the Root Password in the MySQL reference manual.
```

That was weird, I have never seen that kind of message. After that, I started MySQL via the Preference Pane and then use `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -v` command on the terminal for another step. I got an error message saying that :

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'cheetah'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I have also tried to access database through `Sequel Pro` using root as username and blank password, I got access denied message saying that :

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 because access was denied.

Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from your current location is permitted.

MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Okay, I also tried this again using root as a username but 'R>gFySuiu23U'  as a password (which was generated from MySQL). I got connection failed message saying that :

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.

Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).

MySQL said: Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.
```

How could I solve this problem? I remember that MySQL has never got automatically generated a temporary password like this, hasn't it ?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p
Enter password: (enter the random password here)
```

Ref:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization-mysqld.html

Following this, you may reset your password using
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new-password';`

Comment: This did not work for me. I am getting the message `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` no matter what I do

Comment: Instead of random password you should use temporary, auto-generated password. Worked for me (OSX, MySQL 5.7.9, fresh install)

Comment: Using the autogenerated password doesn't work for me - it says "ERROR 1862 (HY000): Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords." ------- I'm mad!!!!

Comment: @T1000 I think adding `--connect-expired-password` option would solve your problem.

Comment: TIP: Make sure `mysql` is in started stated.

Comment: MySQL on Mac is the crappist user experience.
I install it though DMG, generates password.
I start it though settings...
Try to connect, password has expired, wtf..

Try to reset it. ```Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)```.. What a waste of space.

Answer (score 42):

This is what worked for me on OS X Yosemite running MySql v5.7 (installed from the .dmg).

```
cd /usr/local/mysql/bin
./mysql -u root -p --connect-expired-password
```

(Enter the temporary password generated by the installer.)

This gets you into [sandbox mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-sandbox-mode.html) and `mysql>` prompt. Then set desired root password with [SET PASSWORD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html):

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mySuperSecretPassword');
```

Comment: This answer saves me a whole day! I initially install the binary version of 5.7 for mac, the temporary password worked. Later on for some reason mysql crashed on hardware issue and I reinstalled with DMG, then the temporary password popped up during installation failed! I almost giveup untilll use --connect-expired-password, which enabled my to log in with the temporary password

Comment: is --connect-expired-password a valid option?

Comment: @LZH See the sandbox mode link in my answer where --connect-expired-password is documented

Comment: after a while, I figured that the temporary password has some ambiguity for some upper and lower case letters.

Comment: In my case, the installer asked me for a password. I entered it. It asked again and I entered it again.  After installation, this is the only thing that worked.  The DB installer ought to tell you to do this the first time.

Answer (score 38):

Now that the password MySQL had generated is expired, the problem is reduced to getting this password to work again (1) or generate a new one (2). This can be accomplished by running MySQL with the skip-grant-tables option which would make it ignore the access rights:

1. Stop your MySQL server.
2. Add the below at the end of the [mysqld] section of my.cnf file and save it.

   `skip-grant-tables`
3. Start MySQL server.
4. In terminal, type

   `mysql -u root -p`

to get into MySQL command prompt.

5. In the command prompt, type

   `USE mysql;`

to get into the mysql database where it keeps database users.

6. Type

   `UPDATE user SET password_expired = 'N' WHERE User = 'root';`

to let MySQL know the password is not expired (1) or

```
UPDATE user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('YourNewPassword'), password_expired = 'N' WHERE User = 'root';
```

to assign a new password YourNewPassword to root (2).

Comment: @Anton: Thank you, this solution works to me at El capitan 10.11.1

Comment: I try lots of answer on web, but only this works because of other did not mention "USE mysql;" command before sql statement.

Comment: Perfect, this worked for me.

Comment: my.cnf file can be found in location /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 17):

Doing these steps under OSX 10.11 El Capitan and MySQL 5.7.X, should do the trick.

Considering that you already have MySQL installed then..

Open a terminal window and type:

1. sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
2. sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

Since the command fired in the step 2 will be under on going state, you need to open another terminal window and then type:

1. mysql -u root -p
2. UPDATE mysql.user SET password_expired='N', authentication_string=PASSWORD('') WHERE User='root';
3. quit;
4. sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart

**Important**: in the step 2 you must replace  for your password.

Hope it will wok for you.

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: This method worked for me on macOS High Sierra.

My Node.js project using MySQL that was installed with MAMP Pro stopped working when I updated my OS. Now it works again after installing MySQL separately from MAMP Pro.

Comment: Thanks for this note. It worked for me after installing Mysql using the Oracle package that autogenerated a temporary password.  But to stop the mysql server I needed to us the System Preferences MYSQL panel.  I also unchecked the option to start mysql on reboot and instead use step 4 above: sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart  (or start)

Answer (score 5):

### MySQL password expired

Resetting the password will solve the problem temporarily, however, from MySQL 5.7.4 to 5.7.10 (I think to encourage better security) the default value for the `default_password_lifetime` variable is 360 (about a year). For those versions, if you make *no changes to this variable* (or to individual user accounts) all user passwords expire after 360 days.

Typically, from a script you might get the message: "Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords."

So, to prevent automatic password expiry, log in as root (`mysql -u root -p`), then, for *clients that automatically connect to the server* (e.g. scripts.) change the password expiration settings for those clients:

`ALTER USER 'script'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;`

*or* you can disable automatic password expiration for *all users*:

`SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;`

#### Links:

[MySQL: Password Expiration and Sandbox Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-expiration-sandbox-mode.html)
[MySQL: Password Expiration Policy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html)
[Password expiration policy in MySQL Server 5.7](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2014/03/31/password-expiration-policy-in-mysql-server-5-7/)

Answer (score 4):

I'm running macOS Sierra(10.12.3) and I installed mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64.dmg.

The answer from @lesley worked for me with the exception that I needed to add `./` to ensure I was calling the mysql binary in my current working directory. Which is where the aforementioned package was installed.

If you `cd` to `/usr/local/mysql/bin` and run `mysql -u root -p --connect-expired-password`, you could receive the following error.

```
mysql: unknown option '--connect-expired-password'
```

I did. Because simply running `mysql` without providing a path, called a previously installed version of the MariaDB client.

So to ensure you are executing the correct binary, you can either

provide the absolute path

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p --connect-expired-password
```

or the relative path after changing directories

```
cd /usr/local/mysql/bin
./mysql -u root -p --connect-expired-password
```

Both ways should work. Once you are connected to the client, the instruction are the same as above from @lesley.

Enter your temporary password generated by the installer and set your new password.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yourNewPassword');
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. I followed the installation process guide from https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/MySQL_HowTo.html and downloaded DMG archive and installed MySQL on my MAC OS X 10.12.2.

Finally executed the following commands on new Terminal.

```
cd /usr/local/mysql/bin

./mysql -u root -p --connect-expired-password
```

It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 7 worked for me: `El capitan`, `MySQL` installed from dmg and autogenerated password, but made sure to `cd` to `/usr/local/bin/mysql` before entering `./mysql -root -p`  Obvious, but I didn't the first time.

Now to find where all my databases and tables are and how to link them in.

Answer (score 1):

For Mysql 5.7 I use

> shell $ > sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log

Answer (score 0):

The another way to solve this issue is to use an older version of MySQL instead.

I have uninstalled `MySQL version 5.7.9` for Mac OS X 10.9 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive and then install the older version, `MySQL version 5.6.7` for Mac OS X 10.9 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive. This issue is solved. The given autogenerated password before finishing installation of this older version is gone and I can ultimately access the database using root as username and a blank password. Everything is working like a charm!

Comment: I'll recommend using the latest version if you are doing a fresh install.

Comment: @KumarNitin Yeah, I thought so. By the way, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I installed view brew, and I had the same error message until I noticed this caveat:

> We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
>       mysql_secure_installation
>
> To connect run:
>       mysql -uroot
>
> To have launchd start mysql now and restart at login:
>     brew services start mysql
>
> Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
>     mysql.server start

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by running 
    `'mysql -u root -p --connect-expired-password'`
Then input the expired auto-gen password from mysql. Finally got in. Selected mysql db with 
    `'use mysql'`
and then updated user 'root' pw with 
    `'ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your new password'`

Answer (score 0):

This particular one did the trick for me:

As specified in this link: https://www.variphy.com/kb/mac-os-x-reset-mysql-root-password

Do all the steps except executing

```
    UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('NewPassword') WHERE User='root';
```

Execute

```
    UPDATE mysql.user
    SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
```

And then execute 
        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score 0):

Installing MySQL manually by downloading packages for the first time generates a default password for root. Copy and save that. If not done somehow on successive re-installations it does not show that password.

Thus you cannot login to root.
Do the following :

1. Find mysql related entries from system 
   `sudo find / -name mysql`
2. Remove all mysql related entries by doing `rm -rf <mysql_entries_above>`
3. Download latest mysql-server and intall it.
4. You will be promted with a default password which you need to copy.
5. Run `mysql_secure_installation` and paste that password when asked for root.
6. Subsequently follow the steps and change admin password when prompted for.

Answer (score 0):

But in Mysql80-Server,  it is more complicated than 5.7.  In MySQL80 not allow you to update or change password during the config in my.cnf in state "skip grant table". So you need 3 big steps to do

I) change **my.cnf** to *skip-grant-table*

II) login MySQL with *blank password* & *update table to blank password*

III) restart mysql and login with *blank password* and update to *new password*

Step to do: (whatever, you forgot root password, temporary password gen by installation not work, etc. please follow the steps below) In my case on FreeBSD 12.2

1. stop your mysql server by

   ```
   /usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server stop
   ```
2. recheck again whether it is really stop (in case more serious problem than that)

   ```
   /usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server status

   mysql is not running.
   ```
3. find your my.cnf file and add "*skip-grant-tables*" to it.
   (normally before **[Mysqldump]** head)
4. restart mysql

   ```
   /usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server start
   ```
5. login to mysql

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

   when it ask for password, just press enter and you will log into mysql
6. select DB to use

   ```
   use mysql
   ```
7. look at the table user

   ```
   select user, authentication_string,password_expired from user;
   ```
8. update to blank password

   ```
   UPDATE user SET authentication_string = '', password_expired='N' WHERE User = 'root';
   ```
9. quit mysql and make mysql stop
10. goto file my.cnf  then take  "*skip-grant-tables*" out of file.
11. restart mysql again with "mysql -u root -p" enter the blank password
12. then

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'   IDENTIFIED WITH
    caching_sha2_password BY 'YourNewPassword';
```

13. quit mysql and make mysql stop
14. restart mysql again then you will login with your new password