# Can't set new MySQL password from terminal while the temporary one doesn't work

Tags: mysql, macos, unix, terminal

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p'cwY+nbtxt3w' password newpass
```

Old password is a temporary password by MySQL (in the screenshot below). MySQL is running in settings.

Get errors and warnings :

```
mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

Can you explain how to deal with that?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FWqV.jpg]

Comment: You need to execute the command line you showed as the root.

Comment: ditch the single quotes. Jam the password right next to the `-p`

Comment: To change a password, I would go into `mysql -uroot -p`,  enter the password when prompted, and follow the instructions in [The manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html)

Comment: perhaps an issue of localhost vs. 127.0.0.1, try http://stackoverflow.com/a/33332443 , the `-h` issue.

Comment: @Drew the problem is when I do mysql -uroot -p and type a temporary pass, I get the same error

Comment: @Drew the link didn't help also

Comment: ok, perhaps the cnf file and skip grants, that one. Which embarrassingly was similar to my most up voted answer once. Like, the [2nd Half](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31394469) of that answer. Some people don't have access to `mysqld_safe` depending on the distro.

Comment: @Drew I tried that method, but received  `mysqld_safe.pid: Permission denied`

Comment: @Drew Could I miss something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117364/discussion-between-drew-and-vinand).

Comment: Hello? Anybody home? This is all irrelevant. *You need to execute the command line you showed as the root.* With `sudo`, for example.

Comment: I am confident that when he explains the steps he took to solve it, that it all falls into the category of relevant.

Comment: @Drew Unless and unless he does it my way it will never work.

Comment: @EJP I have performed a ton of "I cannot login to my server" questions, and I am delighted to ping you every time I see one. Just point us at some of your answers to them.