# mysql5.7 + macos catalina, mysql default temporary password not working

Tags: mysql

setup: mysql5.7 + macos catalina

I was driven crazy by the issue. Followed mysql official manual installation, but I cannot log in with generated temporary password
[image]

I tried many solutions on other stackoverflow posts, none works for me like below

[Unable to access MySQL after it automatically generated a temporary password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326065/unable-to-access-mysql-after-it-automatically-generated-a-temporary-password)

some guy told me this "sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & but you'll have to figure out how to do that on Mac. Then you can just log into MySQl - mysql -u root from terminal."

I tried

```
jhxins-MacBook-Pro:bin jhxin$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/jhxins-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
2020-06-09T23:45:28.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2020-06-09T23:45:29.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/jhxins-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
```

the expection should be ongoing state, but it ended  immediatelly.  Then 
"mysql -u root" still failed

Comment: You should be able to reset the root password yourself.  Stop the server.  Start it in safe mode -- On Linux that looks like `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` but you'll have to figure out how to do that on Mac.  Then you can just log into MySQl - `mysql -u root` from terminal.  Then issue a `update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';`  And `flush privileges;`  Then `quit;`  --  Stop the server again and restart it normally.

Comment: @Zak I already tried this, not working for me .   1. sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables command ended immediately,  not like ongoing state.  2. mysql -u root    failed.