# Can't connect to remote MySQL server on Windows

Tags: mysql, remote-access, remote-server

I'm trying to set up a MySQL server on Windows that will allow another computer to connect to it remotely. The client computer is getting a 'Can't connect to MySQL server' error in MySQL Workbench.

Both computers are on the same network, and the server is using a static IP address (I have forwarded ports in my router to allow external connections to the public IP address).

What I've tried (suggested by other threads):

- In my.ini, setting `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` / commenting out `bind-address` / commenting out `skip-networking`
- Running `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'USERNAME'@'IP'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'PASSWORD';`. When I run this, I get the error `Using GRANT statement to modify existing user's properties other than privileges is deprecated and will be removed in a future release`; however I can confirm that in Workbench, the user's privileges are all checked (under the 'Users and Privileges' screen).
- In my router settings, forwarded port 3306 on the server's static IP address
- Disabling the Windows Firewall on the server.
- Verified that the MySQL Server Windows Service is running.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Did you `flush privileges` after the `grant` command? Did you put the correct IP there?

Comment: @Dekel I used Workbench to grant the privileges, so just clicked 'Save'. Also tried `flush privileges` anyway to be sure.

Comment: I also tried % for the IP address to match all incoming IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

Ref: Try connecting with mysql cli instead of work bench from the remote machine, so u can isolate that cli client u r able to access the remote DB.  because the following reason might be causing connectivity issue in Workbench.

mysql cli cmd
install mysql.exe client program 
from cmd prompt> mysql -hhostname -uusername -ppass dbname

[Cannot connect to Database server (mysql workbench)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864276/cannot-connect-to-database-server-mysql-workbench)

In MySQL Workbench (5.2.47 CE)

click Mange Server Instances (bottom right corner)

click Connection

in the Connection box select:

Local Instance ($ServerName) - root@127.0.0.1:3306 '<'Standard(TCP/IP)>

click Edit Selected...

under Parameters, Hostname change localhost or 127.0.0.1 to your NetBIOS name

click Test Connection