# Mariadb docker container Can't connect to MySQL server on host (111 Connection refused) with Python

Tags: python, mysql, docker, mariadb

I am trying the connect mariadb with python using docker-compose:

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '2'
    services:
      mariadb:
        image: bitnami/mariadb
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          MARIADB_DATABASE: 'mary_db'
          MARIADB_USER: user2
          MARIADB_PASSWORD: 'pass1234'
      consumer:
          build: ./consumer
          links:
            - mariadb
```

consumer.py

```
    import mysql.connector as mariadb1

    mariadb_connection = mariadb1.connect(host='mariadb',
                                  port=3306,
                                 user='user2',
                                 password='pass1234',
                                 database='mary_db')

    cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor(buffered=True)

    try:
        cursor.execute('DROP TABLE names')
    except:
        pass

    comm = "CREATE TABLE names(id VARCHAR(20), location VARCHAR(100)," \
   "PRIMARY KEY (mac,location)) ENGINE=InnoDB"

    cursor.execute(comm)
    print 'created'
```

The Dockerfile entrypoint is just calling the consumer.py function like:

```
    ENTRYPOINT python -u consumer.py
```

The problem is very randomly (more than %90 of trials), python code cannot connect with database and prints this error:

> File "consumer.py", line 7, in 
>       database='mary_db')   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/**init**.py",
>   line 179, in connect
>       return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py",
>   line 95, in **init**
>       self.connect(**kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py",
>   line 719, in connect
>       self._open_connection()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py",
>   line 206, in _open_connection
>       self._socket.open_connection()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py",
>   line 475, in open_connection
>       errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err))) mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL
>   server on 'mariadb:3306' (111 Connection refused)

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to Database server (mysql workbench)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864276/cannot-connect-to-database-server-mysql-workbench)

Comment: Since this is a mysql or mariadb error message, it is irrelevant whether python or a gui application receives the error message, hence the duplicate.

Comment: @Shadow I don't think its a duplicate; The question is in Docker and setup is different.

Comment: It is irrelevant, since the error is not related to docker. The client tries to talk to the mysql / mariadb server the way you configured it to, but there is no answer. The possible reasons are all discussed in the duplicate topic.

Comment: It was the docker problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with Database or Python code; Its a raise problem coming from Docker, as database needs some time to load and python (consumer.py) container launches faster than database one.

Possible solutions:

docker healthcheck

waittime in docker

add a delay to the python consumer

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to python containers executing prior then properly executing the database container. 
To remove this issue use below lines of code before mysql connection.

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

Your code should look like this:

```
import time
time.sleep(1)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="<host>",
  user="<user_name>",
  passwd="<pswd>",
  database = "<DB_name>",
  buffered=True
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()
```

It worked in my case. Hope it will work for you as well.