# access denied to mysql with non root user and correct password

Tags: mysql

when accessing my local mysql 5.7 server as a non-root user i get an ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' message after entering the password

connecting with sudo i can use any (or blank) passwords and always get a mysql prompt.

how do i need to configure mysql to be able to connect as a non root user

*edit: added question

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access MySQL with non-root account, because you haven't created any MySQL user account yet, the default account is root. You'll need to create an user account. Follow [this steps](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-administration.htm) or here's the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html) to create a user account and grant privileges to the new user account.

Comment: i created a new account and granted all privileges, this solution worked. thx

Answer (score 4):

By logging in to MySQL using socket authentication, you can do it.

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

Then the following command could be run.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Details are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40291452/596021).