# Access denied message when starting HeidiSQL

Tags: mariadb, heidisql

I installed HeidiSQL to use MariaDB.
When HeidiSQL created and opened a session, the following message appeared.

```
/ * Start "MyDB" session * /
/ * Access denied * /
```

Access was denied, but basic SQL was available.

Environment: Win10 x64, MariaDB 10.3, HeidiSQL 9.5.0.5196

Can anyone help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend updating to the most recent version since yours is outdated.

A similar problem has been answered in the following question https://stackoverflow.com/a/51494222/10820177

Basically, "Access denied" errors tell you are able to establish a physical connection but required privileges for your account are missing.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Exactly, access denied messages can be tricky to solve, but you're right, physical connection is already there, so there is at least no firewall blocking you.

Comment: It's an old question, but thank you so much for answering.