# MySQL Workbench Cannot Connect to Database Server (Heroku, JawsDB)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My workbench was previously working fine until recently, but I'm now getting the following error:

[image]

I'm not sure what's relevant so I'll list out everything that I think might be relevant:

- My OS is Windows and I'm using JawsDB & Heroku as my server.
- I've recently tried to mess with the my.cnf file (in an attempt to enable 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE')
- I *think* this is the extent to which I've used mysql_config_editor:  [image]
- I've run "SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;" after logging in to my local sql.
- I've checked numbers 1-4 on the error message. Here is an image of my connection to be sure:
  [image]
- I think I've messed with the NetBIOS at some point, and that might be a problem as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864276/cannot-connect-to-database-server-mysql-workbench), but I don't see "manage server instances" anywhere.

I'm not sure what else might be the issue here. Thanks in advance.

Edit: After trying to connect to the MySQL server through the command line, I get "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'lyl3nln24eqcxxot.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (10060)", which seems to be an authentication error and not a connection error according to [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/330747/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10060). But I'm unsure how to deal with this authentication error if it is one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this constitutes as an answer, but I've managed to establish a connection through my usual wifi (as opposed to a public school's wifi). It looks like either my security settings are different when on a public wifi or the public wifi itself had some sort of security setting that was blocking my connection.