# How to fix python Mysql.connector error 1698 (28000) access denied

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

I set up a MySQL database on Ubuntu 18.04, and am trying to connect via python using `mysql.connector`. The database is on the same computer as the instance of python (Acer predator).

Connecting to the MySQL database through the terminal works. But using `mysql.connector` in python 3.6 keeps producing the following error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1698 (28000): Access denied
>   for user 'root'@'localhost'

I keep seeing troubleshooting tips talking about auth_socket or granting privileges even here in Stack Overflow, but these are all focused on connecting with MySQL, whereas my issue is specific to `mysql.connector` in python.

Code I am using is below, and I've tried it with other users, no password included, and even no host included - but nothing works.

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
       database='exampledatabase',
       user='root',
       password='examplepassword')
```

Comment: P.s. the python instance I am using is just the standard shell produced with 'idle' in the terminal

Comment: Check you connection parameters again else it is issue with MySQL server issue

Comment: So connecting to the server with those credentials works for a node server or some other instance? How did you rule out the SQL server itself being the problem?

Comment: I have no reason to believe SQL is the issue ... could be but I connect to mysql from the terminal. "sudo mysql -u root" brings up mysql in the terminal, and I can work with the database from there

Comment: Try to access without password. Because you used  `mysql -u root`

Comment: Kcorlidy - per my initial question, I have tried without password and any number of other connect() combinations. Nothing works, it seems the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Be advised, after much banging my head the 2nd answer down listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864276/cannot-connect-to-database-server-mysql-workbench ended up doing the trick.

Comment: Was as simple as altering the password associated with the root user I guess. Phew!!